# Построение списка, состоящего из списка файлов, отсортированных по определенному критерию

Tags: c#, файлы, linq, datetime

Суть такова:

1. Сторонняя программа делает 2 (или более) файла с одинаковой датой создания.
2. Я своей программой должен прошерстить все директории и получить эти файлы.

Проблема состоит в том, что каждый файл мне нужно анализировать и составлять ему пару:

Допустим есть 4 файла(обозначу их): x1=`(invoice1.xml + torg1.xml)`, x2=`(invoice2.xml + torg2.xml)`. Все эти файлы были созданы в разное время, но в одну дату. Например файлы `x1` были созданы `15.10.2021 9:00`, а файлы `x2` были созданы `15.10.2021 11:00`

Что мне нужно:

Получить `List<List<string>>` из этой директории.. т.е структура `List<List<string>>` будет следующим

```
myCollection[0] = List<string> => [0]="invoice1.xml", [1]="torg1"
```

```
myCollection[1] = List<string> => [0]="invoice2.xml", [1]="torg2"
```

и так далее...
Я не понимаю, как мне структурировать **по дате и времени** файлы в папке и получить список, состоящий из списков.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файлы нужно сгруппировать по времени.
Проще всего это сделать с помощью LINQ.

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(".");

var groupedFiles = directoryInfo
    .EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .GroupBy(x => x.CreationTime);
```

Тут будут использоваться тики времени. Возможно, это избыточная точность. То есть, если файлы были созданы в течение одной минуты, но с разницей в пару секунд, то они не попадут в одну группу.

Вот так понижаем точность до секунд (миллисекунды и тики отбрасываются):

```
    .GroupBy(x => new DateTime(
            x.CreationTime.Year,
            x.CreationTime.Month,
            x.CreationTime.Day,
            x.CreationTime.Hour,
            x.CreationTime.Minute,
            x.CreationTime.Second));
```

Можно и дальше понижать точность, задавая `0` вместо `x.CreationTime.Second` и т. д.

---

Если нужен непременно список списков, то просто трансформируем группы:

```
var listOfLists = directoryInfo
    .EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .GroupBy(x => x.CreationTime)
        .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

Но это лишняя работа.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, то что нужно!! =)

Answer (score 1):

тебе необходимо получить метаданные файла - там есть дата сохранения.

Или же воспользоваться методом для получения даты создания или последней модификации файла через его абсолютный путь

```
DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\test.txt");
DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\test.txt");
```

т.е. конечный код будет выглядеть приблизительно так.  (код не проверял)

```
var result = List<List<string>>();

string[] directoryFilesPaths = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

foreach(string filePath in directoryFilesPaths){
    var creation = File.GetCreationTime(filePath).ToString();

    var fileInfoPair = List<string>() {filePath, creation};
    
    result.add(fileInfoPair);
}
```

дальше сортируй LINQом как тебе вздумается по любому возможному критерию.

Comment: Это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Получить дату итд я могу.. проблема в том, что я не знаю как мне получить список ```List<List<string>>``` из всех этих файлов с разной датой. Т.е каждый ```List<string>``` элемент из ```List<List<string>>``` должен будет иметь одинаковое время (описал как это выглядит в вопросе). Список, состоящий из списков, которые в свою очередь содержат пути до файлов, с одинаковой датой

Comment: сохрани в Dictionary пары(ключ-значение) - ключем будет выступать путь, а значением - дата. никакой кучи списков не нужно делать

Comment: это необходимо. Мне надо будет файлы определенного контрагента отправлять по API. Т.е мне эти файлы нужно буквально "связать в один пакет (считай как скоросшиватель для документов)". Все эти файлы - xml, я по контенту файлов получаю контрагента, которому и необходимо отправить список файлов. Как таковая дата мне нужна только лишь для формирования этого "пакета" документов, они делаются отдельной программой, поэтому дата создания у них у всех одинаковая

Comment: проапдейтил ответ